# Network sniffer on iOS

Tags: ios, networking, sniffing

I need to do video streaming to iPhone.
However, I don't have a homebrewed application playing the H.264 stream yet.
I have to understand first, how much delay there's for iPhone to receive the first packet/frame.
**Anyone knows how to get some "sniffer" like WireShark on iPhone? Is it possible at all?**

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Fiddler as a reverse proxy and monitor the traffic from mobile devices. I don't know if this will do exactly what you want (I haven't done it in a long time) but the company I work at has analytics products for the various mobile platforms and that was the method we used to monitor their network usage.

http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp